# generate a SAML response with attributes OneLogin

Tags: symfony, onelogin

I'm using Onelogin bundle under symfony2 and as an Identity Provider i need to send a SAML Response to the Service Provider with the user values needed by the SP . i found how to send a Request but i couldn't find how to generate a Response and send it 
any help would be appreciated , Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Onelogin bundle cover the Service Provider part, if you need to generate a SAMLResponse (that means that you need to act as an Identity Provider), then you need another piece of code not the  Onelogin bundle / php-saml that only implements the Service Provider part.

You can get a [Onelogin trial account](https://www.onelogin.com/signup), create there the users and configure a [SAML Test Connector](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector) (that will act as IdP)

If you need to deploy your own IdP, try with [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp) and use as authsource, the [sqlauth:SQL](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/sqlauth:sql) module connected with the symfony2 database (if that is your user source)